# Instantiating child directives in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm having trouble figuring out how to programmatically instantiate directives.  For example, in the [tabbed panels](http://angularjs.org/#components-js) example, suppose I want to have a function to "Add a new tab" in the parent tabs directive; how should the tabs directive instantiate a new pane directive and add it to the DOM?

Answer (score 3):

I would have a scope variable containing the list of panes you want to display, put the HTML for a single pane inside an `ng-repeat`and have the "add a new tab" function simply add another object to the list of panes; Angular's two-way binding would have the list of DOM elements inside the `ng-repeat` updated upon updating the list.

Comment: To clarify -- what's this list of panes?  Is it the $scope.panes list already on the tabs directive (which, I guess, are instances of the pane directive scopes)?  If so, how do I instantiate one of these instances?

Comment: You could, for instance, add to the tabs directive template a button with `ng-click="addNewPane()`, with the tabs directive itself specifying a `$scope.addNewPane` function that creates a new pane object and pushes it into `$scope.panes`.

Comment: How do you directly instantiate a "new pane object" like the ones currently stored in $scope.panes?  They look like $scope instances of the pane directive...